# How to fix the error of org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:kaptDebugKotlin'?

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to compile an application with Kotlin, but I skip this problem by adding the line kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room version"

In the console displays error: cannot access Publisher
  class file for org.reactivestreams.Publisher not found
  Consult the following stack trace for details.

I tried to add rootProject.buildFileName = 'build.gradle.kts' to settings.gradle

```
 // App gradle

 // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
     ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.21'
     repositories {
         google()
         jcenter()
         mavenCentral()

     }
     dependencies {
         classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.0'
         classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

         // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
         // in the individual module build.gradle files
     }

}

allprojects {
     repositories {
         google()
         jcenter()
         mavenCentral()
         maven { url "http://jitpack.io/" }
         maven{url "https://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/kotlin-eap"}
     }
 }


 task clean(type: Delete) {
      delete rootProject.buildDir
 }


 // Module gradle

 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

 apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

 apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

 apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

 android {
     compileSdkVersion 28
     defaultConfig {
         applicationId "dev.rivas.afilia2"
         minSdkVersion 21
         targetSdkVersion 28
         versionCode 12
         versionName "2.2"
         testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
     }
     buildTypes {
         release {
             minifyEnabled true
             proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
         }
     }
 }

 dependencies {
     implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
     implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
     implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-alpha05'
     implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.2.0-alpha01'
     implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
     def anko_version = "0.10.8"
     implementation "org.jetbrains.anko:anko:$anko_version"
     implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
     testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
     androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.1'
     androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
     def room_version = "2.1.0-beta01"
     implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
     kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"
     implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0"
     implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.3.0"
     implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0"
     implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1"
     implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.10.0"
     implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.10.0"
     implementation 'ru.superjob:kotlin-permissions:1.0.2'
     implementation 'com.github.quickpermissions:quickpermissions-kotlin:0.3.0'
     implementation 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho:1.5.0'
 }
```

I hope to solve the error and compile the app

Comment: Did you find an answer?  I am facing the same issue.

Answer (score -1):

The solution I found was to change the version in the gradle in the file gradle-wrapper.properties to the version 4.10.3-all. zip, and the version of the gradle plugin in the file build.gradle top to version 3.2.1

Comment: Is this the real solution?